# Failed to send h2c command

Tags: h2

I'm executing the following command: sudo insmode hello.c, but it's not working as expected:

ERROR: could not insert module hello.ko: Operation not permitted

When I run the command: dmesg | tail -1 is reported:

rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command

How to fix this error? Thanks